# How can one limit Facebook's send dialog to only one recipient?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

> Hello experts,

I have created a fb app for sending private message to user's friend's inbox.We want the users to be able to send their friends a message via our website, but only to one recipient at a time (they will pick their friend from the list on the site, on which we will pre-populate the message).

But when dialog has appear on user's side user can edit and add multiple recipient.i need to restrict user to add and and edit on dialog box.Is there a way to do this, Please provide me a suggestion for it.

Here is the ss http://screencast.com/t/wvbPe06zAi

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `send` dialog, you won't be able to limit the recipient users.

The only other way to enforce a limit of only one user is to post a message to their feed. You can only post to one user's feed at a time. This however is not private and is simply posted on their profile.

For this you'll need to specify a `to` parameter when you initiate your `FB.ui()` dialog. Here is a simple example :

```
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://your.cool.site.com',
  picture: 'http://your.cool.site.com/foo.jpg',
  name: 'My Cool Site',
  to: USER_FBID
};
FB.ui(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from this page [Mutli Friend Selector](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/multi-friend-selector/) in the example below but I replaced the checkbox input with a Radio input to restrict selection to one friend.

You can build a simple UI (Java Script) to allow the User selecting one of his friends using a radio button like this one:

```
function renderMFS() {
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
var container = document.getElementById('mfs');
var mfsForm = document.createElement('form');
mfsForm.id = 'mfsForm';

for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(response.data.length, 10); i++) {
 var friendItem = document.createElement('div');
 friendItem.id = 'friend_' + response.data[i].id;
 friendItem.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="friends" value="'
   + response.data[i].id
   + '" />' + response.data[i].name;
   mfsForm.appendChild(friendItem);
 }
 container.appendChild(mfsForm);

 // Create a button to send the Request(s)
 var sendButton = document.createElement('input');
 sendButton.type = 'button';
 sendButton.value = 'Send Request';
 sendButton.onclick = sendRequest;
 mfsForm.appendChild(sendButton);
});
}
```

After selecting a friend the user will click on the Send button that was generated by the script above.. the function below will be executed once the Send Button is clicked.

```
function sendRequest() {
// Get the list of selected friends
var sendUIDs = '';
var mfsForm = document.getElementById('mfsForm');
 for(var i = 0; i < mfsForm.friends.length; i++) {
   if(mfsForm.friends[i].checked) {
     sendUIDs += mfsForm.friends[i].value + ',';
   }
 }


FB.ui({method: 'send',
 to: sendUIDs,
 name: 'My Great Invite',
 message: 'Check out this!!!',
}, callback);
}

function callback(response) {
console.log(response);
}
```